# Is there an R equivalent to Mathematica's Sow and Reap functions for building lists?

Tags: r, wolfram-mathematica, list-manipulation

Mathematica has an [interesting way of incrementally building a list](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CollectingExpressionsDuringEvaluation.html) (or more than one list) of results that you calculate at various points of a complicated computation.  I'd like to do something similar in R.

In Mathematica, you can collect the list of each argument to each invocation of the [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) function during a computation by wrapping the entire calculation in call to the [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) function.  Does R have any equivalent to these functions?  Could you perhaps emulate it with environments and the `<<-` operator, or would the scoping rules not permit it?

**Edit**: Here's a contrived example.  Suppose I want to produce a sum of cubes, but I want to also to collect the squares of the numbers I used to make the sum of cubes.  I know there may be more idiomatic ways of doing this exact calculation, but it represents getting some final answer while collecting various items produced along the way.

```
reap(sum(sapply(1:100, function(i) { sow(squares = i * i); i * i * i }))
```

I'd want this to return something that has the sum of cubes plus a named variable "squares" containing the list of squares.

Comment: it'd be easier to answer your question if you gave an example and your desired results.

Comment: Contrived example now added!

Comment: Return both values from your function:  `sapply(1:100, function(i) i^(2:3))` or `sapply(1:100, "^", 2:3)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: now imagine it is far more complicated and involves multiple layers of nested functions and lists of things, so I don't want to have to return everything at every level in between. That's where Mathematica's Sow and Reap really shine.

Comment: The function can be replaced with a function of arbitrary complexity.  Its internal workings are immaterial.

Comment: Then can you create a better example? Also, a good example would include not only the input, but clear output. What do you hope to get returned the function (give an explicit example so we can test).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't thoroughly tested this, but it seems to work for your simple example. Here we define `reap` and `sow`

```
reap <- function(...) {
    expr <- substitute(...)
    REAPENV <- new.env()
    parent.env(REAPENV) <- parent.frame()
    x <- eval(expr, REAPENV)
    c(list(x), as.list(REAPENV))
}

sow <- function(...) {
    expr <- substitute(alist(...))[-1]
    for( f in rev(sys.frames())) {
        if(exists("REAPENV", envir=f)) {
            re <- get("REAPENV", envir=f)
            if (is.null(names(expr))) {
                names(expr) <- if(length(expr)==1) {"sow"} else {letters[1:length(expr)]}
            }
            stopifnot(all(nchar(names(expr))!=0))
            for(n in names(expr)) {
                sx <- eval(expr[[n]], parent.frame())
                cv <- if(exists(n, envir=re, inherits=FALSE)) {get(n, envir=re)} else {list()}
                if(length(cv)>0) {
                    assign(n, append(cv, sx), envir=re)
                } else {
                    assign(n, sx, envir=re)
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    invisible(NULL)
}
```

So the `reap()` function basically just defines a new environment and calls it's argument within that context. The `sow` function takes a named parameters list, and evaluates it's parameters and assigns to the nearest enclosing "reap" environment. Finally, `reap()` will return a list with the "natural" return value of expression it was passed as the first element, and then it will add named elements corresponding to the names used during the `sow()` calls. So if you run

```
reap(sum(sapply(1:5, function(i) { sow(squares=i * i); i * i * i; })))
```

you get

```
[[1]]
[1] 225

$squares
[1]  1  4  9 16 25
```

As I mentioned, this seems to work for the simple test case. I'm sure improvements could be made to finding and assigning to the correct working reaping environment. But this might provide a starting point at least should you wish to pursue something like this.

Comment: It's working when I run reap from the top-level environment, but not inside a function: `test.reap <- function() {r <- 1:100; reap(sum(sapply(r, function(i) { sow(squares = i * i); i * i * i})))
}; test.reap()` gives me an error about r not being found.

Comment: @bskaggs Made a small change to `reap()`. Try again.

Comment: Yeah, that did it!  I've been using R off and on for some time, but [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) is still making me think.  This is the third time you responded to one of my questions — thanks for your continued help!