# Getting intermediate results from nloptr in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I am running the `nloptr` package in `R` and am having trouble obtaining intermediate results for the algorithm. The algorithm runs fine, but I don't want the just the final solution and iteration number, but rather, I want to be able to obtain the current value of the objection function at every iteration.  Here is the code I am using

```
library(tgp)
library(nloptr)

#########################################################################################
### 
#########################################################################################

f = function(x){
    ans = cos(pi*(x[1]+x[2]*x[3]+x[4]))+.2*sin(4*pi*(x[5]*x[6]+x[7])/(x[8]+1))
    return(ans)
}

const = function(x){
    ans = numeric(2)
    ans[1] = sin(pi*(x[1]+x[2]*x[3]+x[4]))+.2*cos(4*pi*(x[5]*x[6]+x[7])/(x[8]+1))
    ans[2] = -cos(pi*(x[1]+x[2]*x[3]+x[4]))+.2*cos(4*pi*(x[5]*x[6]+x[7])/(x[8]+1))
    ans[1] = -ans[1]
    ans[2] = -ans[2]
    return(ans)
}

#########################################################################################
###
#########################################################################################

lhs.size = 1
lhs.lower = 0
lhs.upper = 1
x0 = c(lhs(lhs.size,rbind(c(lhs.lower,lhs.upper),c(lhs.lower,lhs.upper),c(lhs.lower,lhs.upper),c(lhs.lower,lhs.upper),c(lhs.lower,lhs.upper),c(lhs.lower,lhs.upper),c(lhs.lower,lhs.upper),c(lhs.lower,lhs.upper))))

COB = cobyla(x0,f,hin=const,lower=rep(0,8),upper=rep(1,8),nl.info = TRUE, control = list(xtol_rel = 1e-16, maxeval = 2000))
```

and so what the object `COB` gives me is:

```
> COB
$par
[1] 0.4209398 0.4932406 0.5175745 0.7786042 0.2980017 0.6785051 0.2313283 0.3872766

$value
[1] -0.2828427

$iter
[1] 559

$convergence
[1] 4

$message
[1] "NLOPT_XTOL_REACHED: Optimization stopped because xtol_rel or xtol_abs (above) was reached."
```

But I want the `$value` for every `$iteration`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possibility. On another question, I defined a set of [reap/sow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25707102/2372064) functions that allow you to collect values over different function calls. If I define a helper function called "sower"

```
sower <- function(f,n=deparse(substitute(f))) {
    function(...) {
        x <- f(...)
        do.call("sow", setNames(list(x),n))
        x
    }
}
```

which wraps a function and collects it's output via `sow()`, I can use that with your invocation

```
rr <- reap(COB = cobyla(x0, sower(f), hin=sower(const), 
    lower=rep(0,8), upper=rep(1,8), nl.info = TRUE, 
    control = list(xtol_rel = 1e-16, maxeval = 2000)))
```

Then you can get the standard return values are still in `COB` but you can also call

```
rr$f
rr$const
```

To get the values of the functions each time they were called. (Again, be sure to include the reap/sow functions defined in the answer to the other function.)

Answer (score 3):

You can add "print level = 3" in the opts part of the code. For example:

```
opts = list("algorithm"="NLOPT_LN_COBYLA",
        "xtol_rel"=1.0e-8, "maxeval"= 5000, 
        "print_level" = 3)
```

and then use `opts` when calling the algorithm,i.e.

```
result <- nloptr(my.data.var,eval_f = Error.func,
               lb=lb,ub=ub,
               eval_g_ineq=constraint.func,
               opts = opts)
```

This will give you ***objective function value*** apart from ***parameters at each iteration.***

Answer (score 1):

We can trace `f` by issuing this statement any time before running `cobyla`.  It will result in displaying the objective value followed by the parameter values each time `f` is evaluated.

```
trace(f, exit = quote(cat(returnValue(), x, "\n")))
```

To remove the trace:

```
untrace(f)
```

Here is a demonstration:

```
> f <- function(x) 2*x
> trace(f, exit = quote(cat(returnValue(), x, "\n")))
[1] "f"
> f(3)
Tracing f(3) on exit 
6 3 
[1] 6

> R.version.string
[1] "R version 3.2.2 Patched (2015-10-19 r69550)"
```

Also, here is the last bit of output when I run the  COB(...) statement in the question after having run the `trace` statement:

```
Tracing f1(x, ...) on exit 
-0.7071068 0.9867454 0.9798806 0.9903225 0.7928568 0.9767687 0.6967606 0.6352815 0.05268439 
Tracing f1(x, ...) on exit 
-0.7071068 0.9867454 0.9798806 0.9903225 0.7928568 0.9767687 0.6967606 0.6352815 0.05268439 
Tracing f1(x, ...) on exit 
-0.7071068 0.9867454 0.9798806 0.9903225 0.7928568 0.9767687 0.6967606 0.6352815 0.05268439 
Tracing f1(x, ...) on exit 
-0.7071068 0.9867454 0.9798806 0.9903225 0.7928568 0.9767687 0.6967606 0.6352815 0.05268439 
Tracing f1(x, ...) on exit 
-0.7071068 0.9867454 0.9798806 0.9903225 0.7928568 0.9767687 0.6967606 0.6352815 0.05268439 

Call:
nloptr(x0 = x0, eval_f = fn, lb = lower, ub = upper, eval_g_ineq = hin,     opts = opts)


Minimization using NLopt version 2.4.0 

NLopt solver status: 5 ( NLOPT_MAXEVAL_REACHED: Optimization stopped because maxeval (above) was reached. )

Number of Iterations....: 2000 
Termination conditions:  stopval: -Inf  xtol_rel: 1e-16 maxeval: 2000   ftol_rel: 0     ftol_abs: 0 
Number of inequality constraints:  2 
Number of equality constraints:    0 
Current value of objective function:  -0.707106791132674 
Current value of controls: 0.9867454 0.9798806 0.9903225 0.7928568 0.9767687 0.6967606 0.6352815 0.05268439
```

Comment: When I ran what you suggested I got this error message: 

> COB = cobyla(x0,f,hin=const,lower=rep(0,8),upper=rep(1,8),nl.info = TRUE, control = list(xtol_rel = 1e-16, maxeval = 2000))
Tracing f1(x, ...) on exit 
Error in cat(returnValue(), x, "\n") : 
  could not find function "returnValue"
>

Comment: I have added a small self contained demonstration.  Try copying and pasting that into your session.  If that does not work maybe you need a newer version of R.

Comment: Or maybe you need to start a new fresh session.

Comment: Interesting, even with the simplest example I am still getting the same error message.  I am using a year old version of R though.... > R.version.string
[1] "R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)"

Answer (score 1):

It can be captured like in the following example:

```
set.seed(1)
train_hist <- c()

# My objective has 13 variables.
objective <- function(x) ...

tempf <- function(x, grad = TRUE) {
    o <- objective(x)
    if (!grad) {
        # Append the latest objective value to history.
        train_hist <<- c(train_hist, o)
    }
    o
}

res <- nloptr::nloptr(
  x0 = runif(13),
  eval_f = function(x) tempf(x = x, grad = FALSE),
  eval_grad_f = function(x) pracma::grad(f = tempf, x0 = x),
  lb = rep(-1e3, 13),
  ub = rep( 1e3, 13),
  opts = list(algorithm = "NLOPT_LD_SLSQP", xtol_rel=1e-03)
)

# Optional:
res$history <- train_hist
plot(res$history, type="l")
```

I used an example with a gradient that calls the objective function **as well**. Essentially, you do not want gradient calls to appear in your history.

If you do not need a gradient (like in global optimization), or your gradient *does not* call the objective, the `if`-part in the temporary function `tempf` can be left out, i.e., compute the result, append, and return.